# How Do I Properly Setup MySQLConnection in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, client-server

I'm new to C#.

I'm developing a client-server software, where the server connect's to the Database to request, write, modify, and delete information from the database.

Now, I have the database setup, and I have it reading from the Database etc.

My question, however, is how many times should I create a connection to the Database?

Most places I read, tell me to make sure to close the connection to the database when I'm done.

However, the server is CONSTANTLY going to be working with the Database... Would it not be more efficient for me to create a global connection to the database, that only closes when the server shuts down... As opposed to creating a connection every time I need to request, write, modify, and/or delete info...?

I'm fairly certain I'm correct about this, I just want other peoples opinions on the matter.

Comment: [Connection pooling.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) Love it. Don't worry about. ADO.NET got this bit very right. (But to more directly answer the question: open a *"new"* database connection when you need it, close the database connection immediately when the the transaction/operation/request is done.)

Comment: Cool had no idea thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may have read is to call `.Close()` (and `.Dispose()`) on the [`DbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx) instance that you use to work with the database.

Generally speaking, ADO.NET providers use **[Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)** to manage connections to the database so you don't have to worry about managing them.